# OOP in Python - having problems getting a particular method to return an output

Tags: python, oop, methods

I am attempting to calculate a fare for the 'Vehicle' class, whereby the fare is equal to the seating_capacity of the vehicle, multiplied by 10. My code is as follows:

```
class Vehicle:
    def __init__(self, max_speed, mileage):
        self.max_speed = max_speed
        self.mileage = mileage

    def seating_capacity(self, capacity=4):
        self.capacity = capacity
        return capacity

    def fare(capacity):
        fare = capacity * 10
        return fare

class Bus(Vehicle):
    def __init__(self, max_speed, mileage):
        Vehicle.__init__(self, max_speed, mileage)

    def seating_capacity(self, capacity=50):
        return super().seating_capacity(capacity)

vehicle = Vehicle(240, 18)
print(f"Vehicle total fare is {vehicle.fare()}")
```

However, when I run the program, I am met with this traceback error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'Vehicle' and 'int'
```

The output should be 40, since the capacity of the vehicle is set to 4 by default. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You need to define `self` as the first parameter to `fare`. It's implicitly assuming the first parameter (`capacity`) is a `Vehicle` object.

Answer (score 0):

```py
class Vehicle:
    def __init__(self, max_speed, mileage):
        self.max_speed = max_speed
        self.mileage = mileage
        self.capacity = 4

    def seating_capacity(self):
        return self.capacity

    def fare(self):
        fare = self.capacity * 10
        return fare

class Bus(Vehicle):
    def __init__(self, max_speed, mileage):
        Vehicle.__init__(self, max_speed, mileage)

    def seating_capacity(self, capacity=50):
        return super().seating_capacity(capacity)

vehicle = Vehicle(240, 18)
print(f"Vehicle total fare is {vehicle.fare()}")
```